# Automatically wrapping labels to fit in print composer window of QGIS?

Tags: qgis, labeling, print-composer

I am creating a set of hiking maps for the Continental Divide Trail. The trail is nearly 3000 miles, so I have about 200 individual maps and over 1000 information labels. I have a shapefile of rectangles that I use in the atlas part of the print composer to determine these individual maps.

The labels are often cutoff by the edges of the map. I need a way for QGIS to reposition or rewrap the labels to fit in the extents.

In the absence of a better solution, I will write a python script to do this for me, but is there another way?

Answer (score 7):

I figured it out. Go the Layer labeling settings window ( Layer >> Labeling ) Click on the blue and orange icon in the upper right hand corner (Automated Placement Engine.) Deselect "Show Partial Labels"